# Changing port for ssl connection in nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, port, ubuntu-server

I want to publish some shiny app from my pc at home. I have configured correctly the ssl certificates and the web is reachable here:

https://shiny-server.modlearth.com:8443/shiny/

The web is accesible, but not without indicating the correct port: 8443, which I have configured also nicely in the nginx file. Here is my nginx config file:

```
server {
        listen [::]:8443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 8443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/shiny-server.modlearth.com-0002/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/shiny-server.modlearth.com-0002/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name shiny-server.modlearth.com www.shiny-server.modlearth.com;

        #location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #        return 301 https://www.modlearth.com$request_uri;
        #}
        location /shiny/ {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3838/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                #proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                rewrite ^(/shiny/[^/]+)$ $1/ permanent;
        }
        location /rstudio/ {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:7878/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                #proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        } 
}

server {
        if ($host = shiny-server.modlearth.com)  
                return 301 www.modlearth.com;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 81;
        listen [::]:81;

        server_name shiny-server.modlearth.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

However, if I use the web without the port, the connection seems to be doing to 443.

```
curl -k https://shiny-server.modlearth.com/shiny/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to shiny-server.modlearth.com port 443 after 30 ms: Connection refused
```

The port 443 and 8443 are open in the router. But, my internet provider says that 443 "is for them" and I can't use it.

How do I get my shiny app through this ?

Comment: It seems like your internet provider might be blocking incoming traffic on port 443, which is commonly used for HTTPS connections. Since you've configured your Shiny app to run on port 8443, you're fine internally, but external users won't be able to access it without specifying the port.

Comment: you have two options to do that 1,reverse proxy from 443 to 8443, 2 by using standalone ssl certificate and specifying port on domain https://shiny-server.modlearth.com:8443/shiny

Comment: The reverse proxy from 443 to 8443 should be done in the router config or in the server config ?